# Continuous data logging and analysis

Tags: python, database, raspberry-pi

**Background**

I'm trying to develop a system operating on raspberry pi that will log data from multiple sensors (specifically distance measurements @ 25 samples/s and GPS NMEA sentences at 1 sample/s) at different rates, and perform some analysis on this data - so I'm dealing with a continuous time-series. If a certain event is detected from this data analysis, an event should be logged. In addition to this, a camera is operating, and should produce video corresponding to the event (~4 seconds in length). Ideally further analysis would be conducted on the video produced, but I might be hitting the limits of the raspberry pi hardware so this could be conducted once recording ends.

At this stage I have implemented a python script to log the data from multiple sensors at different rates using multiple threads. Thinking about the whole stream of data through the pipeline as:

Log data from sensors > detect events from sensor data > log event > make video > video analysis > log video analysis

I'm trying to think about the broader architecture but I'm out of my depth, don't know the unknown unknowns, and would appreciate some suggestions on ways that you might approach this.

**Questions**

1. Does it make sense to do all of this (logging + data analysis etc.) in one script using lots of threads/processes, or is it likely to be better to break the task into a number of different scripts that interface with a database? I see this option as becoming quite convoluted and difficult to code and debug. I'm assuming I would also need to prioritise tasks to ensure data logging doesn't come at the expense of downstream analysis.
2. Does it make sense to use a relational database to log data to a table for each sensor, and a table for events?
3. What tools exist to conduct this sort of analysis for a pipeline with continuous real-time data? e.g. with rolling windows built-in. I'm convinced they exist, but I don't know what is suitably lightweight to run on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found a solution. If you want to do realtime analysis, a streaming service like Kafka or Pulsar may be fit your need. You have to write codes to consume data yourself.

If you just analyze and visualize your data periodically, you may need a database to keep your data first. Your data is time series, so by nature a Time Series DataBase (TSDB) is a good fit. But TSDB can only handle well structured data e.g., cpu, mem. You can add tags as you want.

If your data is free style as logs, you need a log database. The most famous one is ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) but it is super heavy and I don't think it can work on PI. Recently Prometheus team releases a log service and you can take a look. Prometheus also offers a nice TSDB solution targeting docker and k8s.

We are also developing a lightweight TSDB TickTock (https://github.com/ytyou/ticktock) which can even run in RPi-0-w(arm 32).

Disclosure: I am a co-maintainer of TickTock. TickTock is still being actively developed and stress-tested, not in production yet.